# "The xxx property is not a DependencyProperty...", Error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I want to create a WPF component using an attached `DependencyProperty`. I have created my component like the static `DependencyProperty` like that :

```cs
public class DayOffCalenderHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty dateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Date", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DayOffCalenderHelper), new PropertyMetadata { PropertyChangedCallback = DatePropertyChanged });

    private static void DatePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var date = GetDate(d);
        SetIsHoliday(d, CheckIsHoliday(date));
    }

    public static DateTime GetDate(DependencyObject obj)
    {
            return (DateTime)obj.GetValue(dateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDate(DependencyObject obj, DateTime value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(dateProperty, value);
    }
}
```

When I use it in my xaml :

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Helper="clr-namespace:NAMESPACE.Utils">
    <Style
        x:Key="MyStyleKey"
        TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
        <Setter Property="Helper:DayOffCalenderHelper.Date" Value="{Binding}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Everything compiles well and works as I expected but I still have 3 errors in my Visual Studio saying the same thing :

> **Error XDG0041** : The "Date" property is not a DependencyProperty. To be usable in tags, unattached properties must be visible on the target type with an accessible instance property "Date". For joined properties, the declared type must provide the static methods "GetDate" and "SetDate".

What can I do to fix that ? (or avoid this error..)

Comment: Can you please post the code of `CalendarDayButton`?

Comment: The attached property declaration does not adhere to naming conventions. `dateProperty` should be named `DateProperty`.

Comment: Thanks, totaly forgot about this naming conventions @Clemens